# How can I add the return of a Future to a StreamController sink?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter and I don't know if it will be possible to pass the return of a Future to a `Stream` through `Sink` and then display it in a `StreamBuilder`.

I was trying to add variable `turistic` to the `sink` in the second `Future` of the `Provider.dart` but when I go to check if the `sink` has the data with the `log` I get the following:

[image]

[image]

HomePage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:streams/provider.dart';

class FotoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = new AppProvider();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Foto Page'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: provider.appStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.data),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error),
            );
          }

          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Provider:

```
class AppProvider {

  final _appStreamController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  Function get appSink => _appStreamController.sink.add;

  Stream<String> get appStream => _appStreamController.stream;

  void disposeStreams() {
    _appStreamController?.close();
  }

  Future<String> requestFirstAPI(File imagen) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://api...');

    final mimeType = mime(imagen.path).split('/'); // Image/jpeg
    final imageUploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);

    

    dynamic respData = json.decode(resp.body);
    print(respData);
    String urlGenCloudinary = respData['secure_url'];
    print(urlGenCloudinary);
    return requestPlaceClarifai(urlGenCloudinary);
  }

  String turistic;
  Future<String> requestAPI(String url) async {
    final String apiUrl =
        "https://api....";

    final res = await http.post(

    );

    final resReqRes = reqResRespuestaFromJson(res.body);
    print('Valor: ${resReqRes.outputs[0].data.concepts[0].value}');

    turistic = resReqRes.outputs[0].data.concepts[0].id;

    // ADD VARIABLE TO SINK
    appSink(turistic);
    log(appSink.toString());
    return turistic;
  }
}
```

P.S: As such no data is entered because only the CircularProgressIndicator in the app is displayed.

Comment: The log you provided is just a function toString. The builder in your code has a problem with return statements. There are 2 the same checking if statements `snapshot.hasData` so you would always go into the first one with error (the same is the third block)  thats might be a reason why you see the error all the time.

Comment: Thank you @wpazio, I have already corrected the if statements and it is still in CircularProgressIndicator, or I don't know if those statements are being done wrong.

Comment: Where did you call the `requestAPI` method?

Comment: I don't call it , because I read that it is not necessary when the data I need is entered in the stream, I really don't know if I am wrong.